# What is a BulkEditGridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I came across something I've never seen before, `BulkEditGridview`?

I can find a few references to this out there but not much regarding what it actually is and what, if any, difference to just a `GridView`?

If there is none, why does it exist?  Where did it come from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here

http://dotnetdiscussion.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/aspnet-how-to-use-bulkeditgridview-to-save-hours-in-database-editing/

http://mukarrammukhtar.wordpress.com/bulk-edit-gridview-in-net/

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/99001/BulkEditGridView

Comment: Ah, it's a custom user control, I see.  I thought it might be a deprecate control from 1.1 or something that I never heard of.  thanks!